# MapActivity could'nt get connection factory client

Tags: android, google-maps, google-maps-mobile

I've been looking for much on google about the problem, but I have not resolved. The map is displayed, but I located at the point where I want and still giving me the same failure:

> 06-09 12:10:57.231: I/MapActivity(1532): Handling network change
>   notification:CONNECTED 06-09 12:10:57.231:
>   W/IdleConnectionHandler(1532): Removing a connection that never
>   existed! 06-09 12:11:04.829: W/KeyCharacterMap(1532): Can't open
>   keycharmap file 06-09 12:11:04.829: W/KeyCharacterMap(1532): Error
>   loading keycharmap file 06-09 12:11:04.829: W/KeyCharacterMap(1532):
>   Using default keymap 06-09 12:11:57.080: I/MapActivity(1785): Handling
>   network change notification:CONNECTED 06-09 12:11:57.080:
>   E/MapActivity(1785): Couldn't get connection factory client

And I do not understand because I've followed all the steps to generate the api key, my Activity extends from MapActivity, and and I added my android manifiest permits and libraries.

Manifest.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        package="com.XXX.XXX"
        android:versionCode="1"
        android:versionName="1.0" >

        <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="10" />
        <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
        <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION"/>
        <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION"/>


        <application
            android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <uses-library android:name="com.google.android.maps"/>                  
            <activity
                android:name=".MainActivity"
                android:label="@string/app_name" 
                android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar">
                <intent-filter>
                    <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                    <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
                </intent-filter>
            </activity>    
            <activity android:name=".Activities.Gmaps"/>                
        </application>
    </manifest>
```

Gmaps Activity

```
import android.os.Bundle;

import com.google.android.maps.GeoPoint;
import com.google.android.maps.MapActivity;
import com.google.android.maps.MapController;
import com.google.android.maps.MapView;

public class Gmaps extends MapActivity{

    private MapView mapa = null;
    private MapController control = null;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.gmaps);                        

        mapa = (MapView)findViewById(R.id.mapa);
        mapa.setBuiltInZoomControls(true);

        Double latitud = 40.4166909;
        Double longitud = -3.7003454;

        GeoPoint loc = new GeoPoint(latitud.intValue(), longitud.intValue());

        control = mapa.getController();            
        control.setCenter(loc);
        control.setZoom(7);
    }

    @Override
    protected boolean isRouteDisplayed() {
        return false;
    }

}
```

gmaps.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <com.google.android.maps.MapView
        android:id="@+id/mapa"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:apiKey="0htJ1gM0WymyYYokI3eUunfuJ2-XXXXXXXXX" 
        android:clickable="true"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Sorry for my english !! jeje :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sign your application with a keystore and generate an apk for your application using this keystore.Then install this on your device. This would solve your problem.The map api key you are using must be generated with this keystore only.